# atomic make the retainCount+1

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-management

I don't often use property atomic, but I found something is strange.  My test file is not use ARC.
I use a property  `@property(atomic,retain) NSArray* test;` 
Then I just make a test for the thing in the init method. 
like this

```
1) NSArray* testArray = [NSArray arrayWithObject:@"1"];
2) self.test = testArray;
```

After executing 1)

```
[testArray retainCount] = 1
```

After executing 2)

```
[testArray retianCount] = 2
[self.test retainCount] = 3 
[_test retainCount] = 3.
```

Then I change property atomic to nonatomic.  After executing 1)

```
[testArray retainCount] = 1
```

After executing 2)

```
[testArray retianCount] = 2
[self.test retainCount] = 2
[_test retainCount] = 2.
```

so I don't know why. atomic can add retainCount?

Comment: Short answer: `retainCount` is an internal implementation detail and should not be used for anything.

Comment: It is strange that `[testArray retainCount]` and `[self.test retainCount]` could be different.

Comment: @kelin Not really;  the absolute retain count of an object is utterly useless.   The difference is an implementation detail of the compiler and/or the runtime.  It is likely to change between optimization levels, platforms and/or software releases.

Comment: @bbum, but this 2 vars refer the same object, that why it's surprising.

Comment: @kelin The call to `self.test` in the `atomic` case likely calls `return [[_test retain] autorelease];` (along with some atomicity dance).

Comment: @bbum, now I get it, thanks! This is actually the answer for the question.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't do Manual Reference Counting in this day and age. Seriously, there is no drawback to using ARC. The only reason I can think of is, if you need to maintain legacy code that can't be converted to ARC (due to resource allocation priorities, etc.).

Even back in the days of MRC, Apple **strongly** discouraged the direct manipulation of the `retainCount` property: that is just an implementation detail and relying on it will just make your app fragile.

You should instead design your app around object graphs (ownership relationships), whether with ARC or MRC.

Comment: I don't agree with you. While MRC is obsolete, it's useful to track `retainCount` during profiling to understand, what happens with object.

Comment: As I said, "(the design of your app) relying on it will just make your app fragile.". I never said it couldn't be a useful debugging tool.

Comment: @kelin It isn't useful for debugging either.  You have no way of knowing if any of the retains are because of an autorelease pool, an internal implementation detail of the frameworks, because it is captured in a block and/or because of some concurrency shenanigans.

Answer (score 0):

I think *atomic* put a object to current Autorelease poll. It is needed to make the object alive while you work with it (in this moment the object may be released on an other thread).
Try to wrap

```
NSArray* testArray = [NSArray arrayWithObject:@"1"];
self.test = testArray;
```

with AutoreleasePool, and check retainCount after (Then code exit from autorelease poll).
I think you will get retainCount == 1.

Answer (score 0):

The absolute value of the retainCount is completely useless.   You can't infer meaning from it about an objects lifespan nor is it particularly useful for debugging.

See http://www.whentouseretaincount.com for more information.

As for your specific case, the retain count is changing behavior across `atomic` due to implementation details.  If you switch between optimized and non-optimized builds, you'll probably see yet different results.